# Physical laws in all inertial frames

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames

Do there exist physical laws which do not take the same form in all inertial frames?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "form". The actual way to calculate e.g. a gradient even differs within the same frame if you change from Cartesian coordinate to polar coordinates, but it's still a gradient.

Comment: A form is, informally speaking, a way, in which a mechanism operates on the matter. As for your example, by this definition, a gradient is a gradient, no matter what coordinates you use.

Comment: I do not recognize "a mechanism operating on matter" in any way as a description of (the form of) physical law, either formally or informally. But if a gradient is a gradient is a gradient, then all (proper, relativistic) laws have the same form, since they are formulated on the spacetime manifold without reference to any frames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do there exist physical laws which do not take the same form in all inertial frames?

Maxwell's equations (law in one inertial frame) do not have the same form if transformed by the Galilei transformation (another law supposed to address all inertial frames), but they do if transformed by the Lorentz transformation (another law supposed to address all inertial frames).**So it depends on the transformation used.**

If only Lorentz transformation is admitted, are all physical laws of invariant form? I do not think any evidence was found requiring that there is a physical law that is not invariant under the Lorentz transformation. But there may be. Most probably we do not know all physical laws.